# How we Process the authentication using Site.login in @auraenabled method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

How we Process the authentication using Site.login in `auraenabled` method.
When we use

```
PageReference pgreferance = Site.login(email,password, startUrl);
```

in `auraenabled` method it shows the error message of

> PageReference is not a type for @auraenabled method

and it does not return any value back to the component controller.